# Query Enums stored as string using nHibernate Linq Provider

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I currently have an Enum being staved as a string in the database. I now what to wuery and filter on this Enum using the Linq Provider for nHibernate but I keep getting exceptions.

I have tried comparing the Enum to a list of Enums, tried .ToString()
and I am still unable to get it to work.

are the custom conventions only active to the Detached Criteria ?

Answer (score 2):

I use GenericEnumMapper and never had any problems with link queries.

```
Map(x => x.Status).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<MerchantStatus>>();
```

Not sure how to apply this to AutoMapping though because I rarely use it. Maybe something like this

```
.Override<MerchantStatus>(map =>
{
  map.Map(x => x.Status)
    .CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<MerchantStatus>>();
});
```

Comment: dose this also work with .Where(e=> enumCollection.Contains(e.enum))

Comment: I had never used it in that way. I just made a small test case and it is working. I am using fluent-nhibernate 1.2 with the bundled hibernate. Database backend is postgresql.

Comment: I'll give this a try. I had to work around this problem in odds ways so far. thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Fluent NHibernate? If so, you can user Map()... 
Also, make sure your Automapping does not conflict with Fluent NH and that you correctly  registered all your conventions.

Comment: we are using Fluent nHibernate and are using Map(), the conventions are properly registered because we are able to query for entities and the values are saved and populated. the people comes when I try to query on the specific enum field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom IUserType to convert an enum to its string representation and back. There's a good example in C# [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx)

There is one more post abt the same: http://softwareblog.morlok.net/2009/07/02/mapping-enums-to-custom-strings-in-nhibernate/

Hope that helps you..

Comment: do you have an example that uses fluent nhibernate ?